# Make Same JS work for different Divisions Elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I have two parts, **First** and **Second** both are sliders, while I slide for First, it happens for Second also, same for other actions. I do not want to use different JS for the same kind of actions, How can I, I tried a lot but failed.
both **First** and **Second** have the same class. I have a bunch of divisions like this.

You can **run** and see what I mean.

```js
$(".sliderWrapper1").prop("scrollWidth") > $(".catalog-cover").width() && $(".right-button").show();
const slider = document.querySelector(".sliderWrapper1"),
  preventClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault(), e.stopImmediatePropagation()
  };
let startX, scrollLeft, isDown = !1,
  isDragged = !1;
slider && (slider.addEventListener("mousedown", e => {
  isDown = !0, slider.classList.add("active"), startX = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft, scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft
}), slider.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  isDown = !1, slider.classList.remove("active")
}), slider.addEventListener("mouseup", e => {
  isDown = !1;
  const t = document.querySelectorAll("a");
  if (isDragged)
    for (let e = 0; e < t.length; e++) t[e].addEventListener("click", preventClick);
  else
    for (let e = 0; e < t.length; e++) t[e].removeEventListener("click", preventClick);
  slider.classList.remove("active"), isDragged = !1
}), slider.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
  if (!isDown) return;
  isDragged = !0, e.preventDefault();
  const t = 2 * (e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft - startX);
  slider.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - t
}));
var widthc = $(".catalog-cover").width() - 20;
$(".left-button").hide(), $(".left-button").click((function() {
  $(".right-button").show(), $(".sliderWrapper1").animate({
    scrollLeft: "-=" + widthc + "px"
  })
})), $(".right-button").click((function() {
  $(".left-button").show(), $(".sliderWrapper1").animate({
    scrollLeft: "+=" + widthc + "px"
  })
})), $((function() {
  $(".sliderWrapper1").scroll((function() {
    var e = $(".sliderWrapper1").outerWidth(),
      t = $(".sliderWrapper1")[0].scrollWidth,
      n = $(".sliderWrapper1").scrollLeft();
    matchright = parseInt(t - e);
    matchleft = parseInt(n);
    differencerl = matchright - matchleft;
    differencerl <= 5 ? $(".right-button").hide() : 0 === n ? $(".left-button").hide() : $(".right-button, .left-button").show()
  }))
}))
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://wallpaperstacks.sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com/mycss.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ibox bsh">
  <h4>First</h4>
  <div class="projects-catalog">
    <div class="catalog-cover">
      <i class="left-button"></i>
      <ul class="sliderWrapper1">
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Apple
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Banana
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Orange
          </div>
        </a>

        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Apple
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Banana
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Orange
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Apple
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Banana
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Orange
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Apple
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Banana
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Orange
          </div>
        </a>

        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Apple
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Banana
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Orange
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Apple
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Banana
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Orange
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Pine
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Grapes
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Pomeogranate
          </div>
        </a>

      </ul>
      <i class="right-button"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>





<div class="ibox bsh">
  <h4>Second</h4>
  <div class="projects-catalog">
    <div class="catalog-cover">
      <i class="left-button"></i>
      <ul class="sliderWrapper1">
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            January
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            February
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            March
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            April
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            May
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            June
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            June
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            June
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            June
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            June
          </div>
        </a>

        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            July
          </div>
        </a>

        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            August
          </div>
        </a>

        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            September
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            September
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            September
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            September
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            September
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            September
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            September
          </div>
        </a>

      </ul>
      <i class="right-button"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: HTML basics: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul `<a>` cannot be a direct child of UL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made this [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3qoe25bh/39/) to check out.
you have to extract the logic in a function then call the function with different `sliderWrapper` classes.

```js
function slide(sliderWrapper){
$(sliderWrapper).prop("scrollWidth") > $(sliderWrapper).parent().width() && $(sliderWrapper).next(".right-button").show();
const slider = document.querySelector(sliderWrapper),
  preventClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault(), e.stopImmediatePropagation()
  };
      
    let startX, scrollLeft, isDown = !1,
  isDragged = !1;
  
    slider && (slider.addEventListener("mousedown", e => {
  isDown = !0, slider.classList.add("active"), startX = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft, scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft
}), slider.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  isDown = !1, slider.classList.remove("active")
}), slider.addEventListener("mouseup", e => {
  isDown = !1;
  const t = document.querySelectorAll("a");
  if (isDragged)
    for (let e = 0; e < t.length; e++) t[e].addEventListener("click", preventClick);
  else
    for (let e = 0; e < t.length; e++) t[e].removeEventListener("click", preventClick);
  slider.classList.remove("active"), isDragged = !1
}), slider.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
  if (!isDown) return;
  isDragged = !0, e.preventDefault();
  const t = 2 * (e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft - startX);
  slider.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - t
})); 

var widthc = $(sliderWrapper).parent().width() - 20;
$(sliderWrapper).prev().hide(), $(sliderWrapper).prev().click((function() {
  $(sliderWrapper).next().show(), $(sliderWrapper).animate({
    scrollLeft: "-=" + widthc + "px"
  }) 
})), $(sliderWrapper).next().click((function() {
  $(sliderWrapper).prev().show(), $(sliderWrapper).animate({
    scrollLeft: "+=" + widthc + "px"
  })
})), $((function() {
  $(sliderWrapper).scroll((function() {
    var e = $(sliderWrapper).outerWidth(),
      t = $(sliderWrapper)[0].scrollWidth,
      n = $(sliderWrapper).scrollLeft();
    matchright = parseInt(t - e);
    matchleft = parseInt(n);
    differencerl = matchright - matchleft;
    differencerl <= 5 ? $(sliderWrapper).next().hide() : 0 === n ? $(sliderWrapper).prev().hide() : ($(sliderWrapper).prev().show(),$(sliderWrapper).next().show())
  }))
}))
}


slide('.sliderWrapper1')
slide('.sliderWrapper2')
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://wallpaperstacks.sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com/mycss.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ibox bsh">
  <h4>First</h4>
  <div class="projects-catalog">
    <div class="catalog-cover">
      <i class="left-button"></i>
      <ul class="sliderWrapper1">
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Apple
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Banana
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Orange
          </div>
        </a>

        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Apple
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Banana
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Orange
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Apple
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Banana
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Orange
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Apple
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Banana
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Orange
          </div>
        </a>

        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Apple
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Banana
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Orange
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Apple
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Banana
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Orange
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Pine
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Grapes
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Pomeogranate
          </div>
        </a>

      </ul>
      <i class="right-button"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ibox bsh">
  <h4>Second</h4>
  <div class="projects-catalog">
    <div class="catalog-cover">
      <i class="left-button"></i>
      <ul class="sliderWrapper2">
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            January
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            February
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            March
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            April
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            May
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            June
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            June
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            June
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            June
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            June
          </div>
        </a>

        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            July
          </div>
        </a>

        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            August
          </div>
        </a>

        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            September
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            September
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            September
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            September
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            September
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            September
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            September
          </div>
        </a>

      </ul>
      <i class="right-button"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Since when `<a>` i a valid child of UL?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan i was thinking the same way? maybe the OP has an answer for that!

Comment: I would not let a mistake like that one slip trough my answer. We're not here to blueprint OP's mistakes, are we ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your initial code only refer to a single selector `.sliderWrapper1` which is used in the 2 sliders. To fix that you can wrap your code inside a function `animateSlider` that take as parameter an **unique** selector and call it for both sliders. Then in your code you will have to always select elements that are a child of the given selector to be sure that one function call doesn't impact the wrong slider.

Here is an example of this `animateSlider` function. Please notice that I updated in the DOM the `sliderWrapper1` to `slider-wrapper` and added the ids `#slider1` and `#slider2`:

```js
const animateSlider = (sliderSelector) => {
  const slider = document.querySelector(`${sliderSelector} .slider-wrapper`);
  const $slider = $(sliderSelector)
  const $sliderWrapper = $(`${sliderSelector} .slider-wrapper`)
  const $sliderCatalog = $(`${sliderSelector} .catalog-cover`)
  const $rightBtn = $(`${sliderSelector} .right-button`)
  const $leftBtn = $(`${sliderSelector} .left-button`)

  $slider.prop("scrollWidth") > $sliderCatalog.width() && $rightBtn.show();

  const showBtns = () => {
    $rightBtn.show();
    $leftBtn.show()
  }

  const sliderWrapper = document.querySelector(`${sliderSelector} .slider-wrapper`),
    preventClick = e => {
      e.preventDefault(), e.stopImmediatePropagation()
    };
  let startX, scrollLeft, isDown = !1,
    isDragged = !1;
  sliderWrapper && (sliderWrapper.addEventListener("mousedown", e => {
    isDown = !0, sliderWrapper.classList.add("active"), startX = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft, scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft
  }), slider.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    isDown = !1, sliderWrapper.classList.remove("active")
  }), slider.addEventListener("mouseup", e => {
    isDown = !1;
    const t = sliderWrapper.querySelectorAll("a");
    if (isDragged)
      for (let e = 0; e < t.length; e++) t[e].addEventListener("click", preventClick);
    else
      for (let e = 0; e < t.length; e++) t[e].removeEventListener("click", preventClick);
    sliderWrapper.classList.remove("active"), isDragged = !1
  }), sliderWrapper.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
    if (!isDown) return;
    isDragged = !0, e.preventDefault();
    const t = 2 * (e.pageX - sliderWrapper.offsetLeft - startX);
    sliderWrapper.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - t
  }));
  var widthc = $sliderCatalog.width() - 20;
  $leftBtn.hide(), $leftBtn.click((function() {
    $rightBtn.show(), $sliderWrapper.animate({
      scrollLeft: "-=" + widthc + "px"
    })
  })), $rightBtn.click((function() {
    $leftBtn.show(), $sliderWrapper.animate({
      scrollLeft: "+=" + widthc + "px"
    })
  })), $((function() {
    $sliderWrapper.scroll((function() {
      var e = $sliderWrapper.outerWidth(),
        t = $sliderWrapper[0].scrollWidth,
        n = $sliderWrapper.scrollLeft();
      matchright = parseInt(t - e);
      matchleft = parseInt(n);
      differencerl = matchright - matchleft;
      differencerl <= 5 ? $rightBtn.hide() : 0 === n ? $leftBtn.hide() : showBtns()
    }))
  }))
}

animateSlider("#slider1")
animateSlider("#slider2")
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://wallpaperstacks.sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com/mycss.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider1" class="ibox bsh">
  <h4>First</h4>
  <div class="projects-catalog">
    <div class="catalog-cover">
      <i class="left-button"></i>
      <ul class="slider-wrapper">
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Apple
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Banana
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Orange
          </div>
        </a>

        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Apple
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Banana
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Orange
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Apple
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Banana
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Orange
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Apple
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Banana
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Orange
          </div>
        </a>

        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Apple
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Banana
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Orange
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Apple
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Banana
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Orange
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Pine
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Grapes
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            Pomeogranate
          </div>
        </a>

      </ul>
      <i class="right-button"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>





<div id="slider2" class="ibox bsh">
  <h4>Second</h4>
  <div class="projects-catalog">
    <div class="catalog-cover">
      <i class="left-button"></i>
      <ul class="slider-wrapper">
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            January
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            February
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            March
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            April
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            May
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            June
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            June
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            June
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            June
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            June
          </div>
        </a>

        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            July
          </div>
        </a>

        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            August
          </div>
        </a>

        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            September
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            September
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            September
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            September
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            September
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            September
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="slide" href="https://wikipedia.org">
          <img height="50" width="50" class="img-circle tags" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
          <div class="sidekro">
            September
          </div>
        </a>

      </ul>
      <i class="right-button"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry! but in orignal JS, if the elements within <ul> is less than scroll width, arrows become hidden, you can check by removing all <a> tags except one, arrow still persists.

Comment: `UL > A` seems invalid to me :\